# Excel - Multi Column Look-up & Match

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, match, lookup

I have currently generated a sheet as shown in Table below to see the URL's of liked photos from a particular Instagram user on my page.

[image]

Now I want to create another Excel doc like this (BOOK2.XLSX) that auto-populates Yes/No if the Instauser (row) has liked the photo (column) referred to in Book1.XLSX

[image]

What is the formula that I should write in B3:C4?

Comment: Sounds like you want to do a multi-column lookup (id and url) which isn't supported by excel. There is a work-around: https://exceljet.net/formula/vlookup-with-multiple-critiera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write something like the following in cell `B3` and drag it across and down.

```
{=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B$2,IF(BOOK1.xlsx!$A$2:$A4=$A3,BOOK1.xlsx!$B$2:$B4),0)),"Yes","No")}
```

It is an **array formula** so need to be confirmed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in the formula bar.

**IF** function will "filter" the links, **MATCH** will check if the link on your second sheet is present in the filtered range of links from the first sheet, **ISNUMBER** will return `TRUE` for a match, and lastly use another **IF** to return `Yes` or `No` as desired.

Comment: Brilliant answer. This helped me. Thank you